# Why is something fried on a griddle called grilled?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage

To my understanding, to [grill](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grill) is cooking with a heat source located beneath an open slatted grate (or ribbed closed pan).  (For example, using a barbecue grill on one's patio.)

The word [grill](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=grill&allowed_in_frame=0) is derived from the French for gridiron *gril* which is derived from the Latin *craticula* (gridiron, or small griddle).

So, how did this definition expand to the sense of frying on a griddle to be called grilling?  For example, a grilled cheese sandwich.  Does this actually date back to the Latin definition?  Is there a chain from Latin to English for this definition?

Why wouldn't we just call this griddled?

Comment: Your understanding of the meaning of _grill_ seems to be constrained. Even the link you provide lists this definition: _to fry or toast (something, such as a sandwich) on a hot surface_.

Comment: @J.R. But, when you look at most other definitions, it says to heat over grates or bars.  I'm asking how did the definition expand to include that.

Comment: @J.R., the question is *why* does grill have both meanings? Why do we deliberately confuse ourselves by calling a grilled cheese sandwich a *grilled* cheese sandwich when it never so much as *saw* a grill, never mind being cooked on one?

Comment: @Marthaª Yes, thank you.  That is exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: Okay, David. I need to do more homework. :)

Comment: @Marthaª - Yes, the question is [evolving](http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/cb079bb3-8153-4a25-9ff0-03737c4a3175/view-source) into what you say. My initial comment may have helped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Griddle, grill,* and *gridiron* all ultimately derive from the same root (Online Etymology Dictionary):

[**gridiron (n.)**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gridiron&allowed_in_frame=0)

> cooking utensil, early 14c., *griderne*, alteration (by association with iron) of *gridire* (late 13c.), a variant of *gridil* (see ***griddle***). Confusion of “l” and “r” was common in Norman dialect. Also a medieval instrument of torture by fire. As the word for a U.S. football field, by 1896, for its lines.

[**griddle (n.)**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=griddle&allowed_in_frame=0)

> shallow frying pan, early 13c., apparently from Anglo-French *gridil*, Old North French *gredil*, altered from Old French *graille*, from Latin *craticula* (see ***grill***).

[**grill (n.)**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=grill&allowed_in_frame=0)

> “gridiron,” 1680s, from French *gril*, from Old French *greil*, alteration of *graille* “grill, frating, railings, fencing,” from Latin *craticula* “gridiron, small griddle,” diminutive of *cratis* “wickerwork,” perhaps from PIE **kert-* “to turn, entwine.” In many instances, Modern English *grill* is a shortened form of ***grille***, such as “chrome front of an automobile.”

[**Grilling**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grilling) is a cooking method that uses any of these devices to apply dry heat to the surface of food (Wikipedia):

> Food to be grilled is cooked on a grill (an open wire grid such as a gridiron with a heat source above or below), a grill pan (similar to a frying pan, but with raised ridges to mimic the wires of an open grill), or griddle (a flat plate heated from below).

While a **grill (n.)** is usually a device with a wire rack, raised ribs, or similar grid pattern, there are exceptions like the [flattop grill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flattop_grill) that have a flat surface like a griddle. And we can **grill (v.)** food on a griddle,* because the cooking method is essentially the same regardless of the surface you use. Or to put it another way: The verb for grilling hasn’t become as specialized as the names of the grilling tools, and the adjective *grilled* comes from its participle.

---

<sup>* Yes, you can griddle (v.) food too, but [it’s a very uncommon usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grill_VERB%2C+griddle_VERB&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrill_VERB%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgriddle_VERB%3B%2Cc0).</sup>

Comment: Very nice answer.  I think you've found the link I was missing there.  Thanks!

Comment: @Bradd Szonye - Awesome answer! Well done.